# Java docs for httpclient and httpcore jars

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Where can I find the java docs for **httpclient-4.5.1.jar** and **httpcore-4.4.3.jar** that comes bundled with selenium webdriver(v.2.49)?

I can only find a 4.5.2 version for the httpclient jar at https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/

Or is that the same one to use for version 4.5.1?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in these [release notes](https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient/RELEASE_NOTES-4.5.x.txt), the 4.5.x releases are mostly bugfixes. Similarly, if you google any 4.5.1 API links, you'll automatically arrive at 4.5.2.

So don't worry about it, you can use the available Javadocs without any caveats.